# Can't change width when annotating bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, typeerror

I'm creating a stacked horizontal bar graph with 3 segments using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_stacked_hbar(data):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

    ylabels = list(data.keys())
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

    c = []
    v = []           
    for key, val in data.items():
        c.append(key)
        v.append(val)
    v = np.array(v)
    print(v)

    plt.barh(range(len(c)), v[:,0], width=1, color='red', 
             edgecolor='w',linewidth=2, tick_label=ylabels, label=labels[0])
    plt.barh(range(len(c)), v[:,1], width=1, left=v[:,0], color='orange', 
             edgecolor='w', linewidth=2, label=labels[1])
    plt.barh(range(len(c)), v[:,2], width=1, left=(v[:,0]+v[:,1]), color='yellow', 
             edgecolor='w', linewidth=2, label=labels[2])

    for p in ax.patches:
            left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
            if width != 0.0:
                ax.annotate(str(int(width)), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), 
                            ha='center', va='center', size = 12)

    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, -0.15), loc=3, prop={'size': 14}, frameon=False)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(len(ylabels)), ylabels)
    plt.show()

data = {'A': [8, 7, 2], 'B': [0, 2, 0], 
                 'C': [3, 2, 4], 'D': [0, 4, 0], 
                 'E': [0, 1, 1], 'F': [0, 1, 0], 
                 'G': [0, 0, 0]}

create_stacked_hbar(data)
```

The issue is that in attempting to set `width = 1` in the bars throws a type error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

removing width allows to the code to work, but I do need to increase the width of the bars in the chart. I suspect this has to do with the annotation code I use in this case. Does anyone have any suggestions on getting around this?

Also note I am unable to use the `"dataframe.plot.barh(data, stacked=True)"` method via pandas to generate this chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a horizontal bar plot, the `width` parameter corresponds to the data, so in your example you are passing both `v[:,0]` and `1` as `width`. If you are trying to specify the height because you do not desire whitespace between the bars you need to set `height=1`, consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Seeded for reproducing
np.random.seed(1)
v1 = abs(np.random.randn(10))
v2 = abs(np.random.randn(10))
v3 = abs(np.random.randn(10))
c = range(10)

plt.title("Sample bar plot")
plt.barh(c, v1, height=1, alpha=0.8, color='r')
plt.barh(c, v2, height=1, left=v1, alpha=0.8, color='b')
plt.barh(c, v3, height=1, left=v1+v2, alpha=0.8, color='g')
plt.show()
```

This will give you

[image]

Where removing the `height=1` specification would give you

[image]